# bpy - how to select an image running blender in -background mode so an operator can use it?

Tags: python, image, selection-tools, command-line, operator

I need to invert an image running blender from the command line using the `-background` flag. To archive it I need to make the image active and later apply the `invert` operator.

I managed to select and invert the image with Blender running the UI, with the following code:

```py
# Select the active image
m = bpy.context.area.type
bpy.context.area.type = "IMAGE_EDITOR"
bpy.context.area.spaces.active.image = myImageToInvert

# Operate over the selected image
bpy.ops.image.invert(invert_r=True, invert_g=True, invert_b=True)
```

But this code **does not run when Blender is called from the command line with the `-background` flag**, because the UI is not loaded so `bpy.context.area` is `null`.

**How can I select the image (`myImageToInvert`) in the background so `bpy.ops.image.invert()` can operate over my image?**

*Thank you*

Comment: Is this the only operator you'd like to use? Otherwise you might want to invert the image using image magic: https://superuser.com/questions/1194468/invert-colors-with-imagemagick ...?

Comment: if this is just an external program or a python script use ffmpeg or other libraries instead of bpy

Comment: Is more about the control of Blender's internally selected image. Is common to have to apply other Blender Operators over the selected image as [`bpy.ops.image.pack()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.image.html#bpy.ops.image.pack)... So I can automate all the pipeline, not just the invert process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Edit) Deleted **1. Solution**

**2. Solution**
This code inverts, the color of a picture. Maybe a bit slower than the Operator but not by much.

It's use `bpy.data` so you have to input the name of the picture to get it.

```
import bpy

def invert(image, invert_r = True, invert_g = True, invert_b = True, invert_a = True):
    pixels = list(image.pixels)
    if invert_r: 
        for i in range(0, len(pixels), 4): # R
            pixels[i] = 1 - pixels[i]
    if invert_g:
        for i in range(1, len(pixels), 4): # G
            pixels[i] = 1 - pixels[i]
    if invert_b:
        for i in range(2, len(pixels), 4): # B
            pixels[i] = 1 - pixels[i]
    if invert_a:
        for i in range(3, len(pixels), 4): # A
            pixels[i] = 1 - pixels[i]
    image.pixels = pixels
            
#Example           
image = bpy.data.images['Untitled']     
invert(image, invert_a = False)
```

You could also use this code to input a sequence of images
(exchange this with the code after `#Example`).

```
images = ['Untitled', 'Untitled.001']
for image in images:
    invert(image, invert_a = False)
```

Comment: As explained in question in background mode `context.area is None` hence method 1 above is also out.

Comment: A sorry, missed that

Comment: #2 is significantly slower/more memory-hungry than the operator. You can speed it up a bit with numpy/foreach. Something [like this](https://pastebin.com/sP8ykmDM).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this solution (#2) still leaves the image unselected for `bpy.ops.image.invert()` and all other operators, so any other operation should be re-implemented. There is no way to simply select the image data so Blender can use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
win = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0]
area = win.screen.areas[0]
area.type = "IMAGE_EDITOR"
override = bpy.context.copy()
override['window'] = win
override['screen'] = win.screen
override['area'] = win.screen.areas[0]
override['area'].spaces.active.image = bpy.data.images['Untitled']

bpy.ops.image.invert(override, invert_r=True, invert_g=True, invert_b=True)
```

I have this as another solution, but Blender always crash with an **exception_access_violation** if the operator get called. If somebody has a solution for this it would probably work.

Comment: This solution still relies in the UI so running in background mode will crash.